# Qt Quick example run error on arm platform

Tags: qt, qt-quick, egl

When I compile a Qt quick project, and run it on freescale imx6 solo board (arm platform), I get an error (see below). When I make a widget project, it runs fine.

> ./clocks -platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0 -plugin
>   evdevtouch:/dev/input/event4 
>   **QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment. This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!** Failed to
>   create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options
>   QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1,
>   blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples
>   -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0)

This is my Qt 5.6.0 configuration item. Did I miss something?

```
Build options:   

Configuration .......... accessibility
accessibility-atspi-bridge audio-backend c++11 clock-gettime
clock-monotonic compile_examples concurrent cross_compile dbus
dbus-linked egl eglfs enable_new_dtags evdev eventfd fontconfig
full-config getaddrinfo getifaddrs inotify ipv6ifname large-config
libudev linuxfb medium-config minimal-config mremap neon no-gif
no-harfbuzz opengl opengles2 openvg pcre png posix_fallocate qpa qpa
reduce_exports release rpath shared small-config system-freetype
system-jpeg system-png system-sqlite system-zlib threadsafe-cloexec
tslib xcb xcb-plugin xcb-qt xcb-sm xcb-xlib xinput2 xkbcommon-qt xlib
xrender    

Build parts ............ libs   
Mode ................... release
Using sanitizer(s)...... none   
Using C++ standard ..... c++11   
Using gold linker....... no   
Using new DTAGS ........ yes  
Using PCH .............. no   
Using LTCG ............. no   

Target compiler supports:
Neon ................. yes

Qt modules and options:   Qt D-Bus ............... yes (linked to
dbus-1)   
Qt Concurrent .......... yes   
Qt GUI ................. yes 
Qt Widgets ............. yes   
Large File ............. no   QML
debugging .......... yes   
Use system proxies ..... no

Support enabled for:   
Accessibility .......... yes   
ALSA ................... no   
CUPS ................... no   
Evdev .................. yes   
FontConfig ............. yes   
FreeType............... yes 

(system library)   
Glib ................... no  
GStreamer .............. no   
GTK theme .............. no   
HarfBuzz ............... no   
Iconv .................. no   
ICU .................... no   

Image formats: 
GIF .................. no
JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using system library)
PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using system library)         libinput................ no   

Logging backends: 
journald ............... no
syslog   ............... no   
mtdev .................. no   

Networking: 
getaddrinfo .......... yes
getifaddrs ........... yes
IPv6 ifname .......... yes
libproxy.............. no
OpenSSL .............. no   
NIS .................... no   

OpenGL / OpenVG: 
EGL .................. yes
OpenGL ............... yes (OpenGL ES 2.0+)
OpenVG ............... yes-auto   
PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)   
pkg-config ............. yes    
PulseAudio............. no   

QPA backends: 
DirectFB ............. no
EGLFS ................ yes
EGLFS i.MX6 ........ no
EGLFS i.MX6 Wayland. no
EGLFS EGLDevice .... no
EGLFS GBM .......... no
EGLFS Mali ......... no
EGLFS Raspberry Pi . no
EGLFS X11 .......... no
LinuxFB .............. yes
Mir client............ no
XCB .................. yes (bundled copy)
**EGL on X ........... no**
GLX ................ no
MIT-SHM ............ yes
Xcb-Xlib ........... yes
Xcursor ............ yes (loaded at runtime)
Xfixes ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
Xi ................. no
Xi2 ................ yes
Xinerama ........... yes (loaded at runtime)
Xrandr ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
Xrender ............ yes
XKB ................ yes
XShape ............. yes
XSync .............. yes
XVideo ............. yes   
Session management ..... yes   

SQL rivers: 
DB2 .................. no
InterBase ............ no
MySQL ................ no
OCI .................. no
ODBC ................. no
PostgreSQL ........... no
SQLite 2 ............. no
SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using system library)
TDS .................. no   
tslib .................. yes   
udev .................. yes   
xkbcommon-x11........... yes (bundled copy,

XKB config root: /usr/share/X11/xkb)   
xkbcommon-evdev......... no  
zlib ................... yes (system library)

NOTE: Qt is using double for qreal on this system. This is binary
incompatible against Qt 5.1. Configure with '-qreal float' to create a
build that is binary compatible with 5.1.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'. Once everything is
built, you must run 'make install'. Qt will be installed into
/usr/local/QT

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from the
previous build.
```

I searched on the Internet, and found EGL on X should be yes. How can I set this item?